# Jquery file upload internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Jquery File Upload to upload files around 30mb. I'm using the chunked option so the plugin breaks the file into 30, 1 mb pieces. Unfortunately on my remote server (shared hosting) I get an 500 Internal Server Error after about 10mb or 10 chucked POSTs to the PHP upload script.

The script works 100% on localhost, and also works on my remote server if the file is smaller which leads me to believe its not the code nor the plugin but rather my server. Any idea why this is happening? I can't imagine its an execution time limit as its not one request, but many smaller ones.

Comment: I might be a complete idiot but... isn't the script that is doing the upload only running when it is receiving a ajax post from jquery? so if the individual post was taking too long the problem would be persistent for uploads of all sizes. its not like a typical file upload.

Comment: @Connum yea one POST per request. sort of typed my last comment as you commented :)

Comment: its strange because a normal post, no jquery, works just fine. but isn't as nice with all the progress bars and what not

Comment: That's really strange indeed... Maybe your hoster uses some kind of spam protection that limits the number of requests within a specific time period? Can you temporarily hack in a delay of a few seconds between each chunk to see whether it works when the requests take place in a longer time frame?

Comment: i wouldn't know how to do that to be honest as I dont even know the method of how it chunks. right now I've removed the chunked aspect (so its like a regular post with progress bar) and that works. i think im going to have to ask my host for the error log to see what might be causing it, as i doubt theyll even understand what im talking about.

Comment: Yup, seems like there's not much else you can do! =/ good luck! And don't forget to add your own answers once you solved this.